# FPDF salto de línea en celda

Tags: php, fpdf

Buenas tardes a todos!

Estoy trabajando con FDPF y tengo un problema con las celdas,es como si me metiese en cada celda un salto de línea, y por tanto en todas las celdas tengo una línea en blanco debajo del texto que quiero que aparezca en la celda.

He cogido de un ejemplo unos funciones para escribir varias lineas en cada celda y cosas del estilo.

Os dejo el código:

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
var $widths;
var $aligns;

function SetWidths($w)
{
    $this->widths=$w;
}

function SetAligns($a)
{
    $this->aligns=$a;
}

function Row($data)
{
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    $h=8*$nb;
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
        $this->MultiCell($w,8,$data[$i],0,$a);
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
    }
    $this->Ln($h);
}

function CheckPageBreak($h)
{
    if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
}

function NbLines($w,$txt)
{
    $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb=strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 and $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep=-1;
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l=0;
    $nl=1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        $c=$s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            $i++;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep=$i;
        $l+=$cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            }
            else
                $i=$sep+1;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
}
```

Y así escribo por ejemplo unas celdas:

```
$pdf->SetWidths(array(24,100));
$pdf->Row(array('Material/Tecnica','material'));
$pdf->SetWidths(array(24,100));
$pdf->Row(array('Ubcacion','ubicacion'));
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

El valor por defecto de `Ln()` es igual a la altura de la última celda impresa, por lo que no es necesario poner `$h`

```
    function Row($data)
    {
        $nb=0;
        for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
            $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
        $h=8*$nb;
        $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
        for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        {
            $w=$this->widths[$i];
            $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
            $x=$this->GetX();
            $y=$this->GetY();
            $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
            $this->MultiCell($w,8,$data[$i],0,$a);
            $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
        }
        //Por defecto, el valor de Ln() es igual a la altura de la última celda impresa.
        $this->Ln();
    }
```

Comment: Gracias @ Pedro Prada, he comentado esa línea y me ha puesto todas las celdas seguidas unas de otras ... Yo he pensado que quizás el problmea sea $h=8*$nb;, que haya que darle un valor menor

Comment: Modificada la respuesta